# Check that the next FirstOnlyDesignNumber is the value of the previous NextDesignNumber In PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I have the following code:

```
try
    {
        #Connect to the SQL server and retrieves the data
        $query = 'Query.sql'
        $SQLConnection = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "$Instance" -Database $DB -InputFile $query -Credential (Get-Credential) -As DataSet
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
    #Output the retrieved data
    $table = $SQLConnection.Tables[0]
    $count = $table.Rows.Count
    $NextDesignNumber = ""
    if (-not $count -eq 0)
    {
        foreach ($row in $table.Rows){
        $Obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
        FirstOnlyDesignNumber = $row.'First/Only Design Number'  
        ApplicationCount = $row.'Application Count'
        NextDesignNumber = [int]$row.'First/Only Design Number' + [int]$row.'Application Count'
        }
    }
}`
```

Which produces:

```
FirstOnlyDesignNumber ApplicationCount NextDesignNumber
--------------------- ---------------- ----------------
1231231                              1          1231232
```

I want to check that the next FirstOnlyDesignNumber is the value of the previous NextDesignNumber i.e.;

```
FirstOnlyDesignNumber ApplicationCount NextDesignNumber
--------------------- ---------------- ----------------
1231231                              1          1231232
1231232                              4          1231236
```

If the next FirstOnlyDesignNumber is the value of the previous NextDesignNumber, do nothing, else do something.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
Compare-Object $Obj.FirstOnlyDesignNumber $Obj.NextDesignNumber
```

and:

```
If($Obj.FirstOnlyDesignNumber -notmatch $Obj.NextDesignNumber){
        //do something
}else{
        //do nothing
}
```

I don't get the expected output.

Comment: You'd need to capture the results, then use a `For(){}` loop. Something like `For($i=0; $i -lt $Records.count; $i++){If($Records[$i].NextDesignNumber -ne $Records[$i+1].NextDesignNumber){Write-Warning "Mismatch on record $i/$($i+1)"}}`

Comment: Post same of the returned table.  You can use a JOIN.

Comment: Or in a (/your) foreach: `$Records | % { $Next = $null } { if ( $Next -and $Next -ne $_.FirstOnlyDesignNumber) { Write-Warning "Mismatch" }; $Next = $_.NextDesignNumber }` or as @jdweng mentions, do a (self) [join](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule):  `FullJoin $Records -on FirstOnlyDesignNumber -eq NextDesignNumber` (which will reveal a link even if it ended up somewhere else).